# Given a point $(x,y,z)$ and an azimuth, dip and distance calculate the end point $(x,y,z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a 3d Point $(x, y, z)$ with a distance, azimuth and dip to an unknown ending point. How can i compute the coordinate of the end point. dip and azimuth are in degrees.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Particularly pay attention to the "provide context" part.